# htaccess redirect all urls except two

Tags: php, .htaccess

Currently I am redirecting all URLs to my `index.html` files:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=302]
```

I want to exclude two URLs, for example:

```
www.mydomain.com/i-am-a-domain
www.mydomain.com/super-cool
```

I found several snippets to exclude URLs, but I was not able to include them, because they use a different setup (at least I think so).

As `RewriteCond` sets conditions, i guess I have to add a line here. I have tried adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(i-am-a-domain|super-cool)\ [NC]
```

Which does not work. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your existing condition as this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(index\.html|i-am-a-domain|super-cool)/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L,R=302]
```

However if you have other rules also in this .htaccess then I suggest using `THE_REQUEST` variable which doesn't get overwritten after execution of some internal rewrite rules.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+(index\.html|i-am-a-domain|super-cool)[?\s/] [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)\sHTTP
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L,R=302]
```